# Ensure during compilation that only objects from same factory are used together

Tags: c++

I want to ensure that instances of `Thing` created by different instances of `Thing::Factory` cannot be `combine`d.

The following code works does just that, at *runtime*:

```
#include <cassert>

struct Thing {
  struct Factory {
    Thing make() {return Thing(this);}
  };

  static void combine(Thing t1, Thing t2) {
    assert(t1.factory == t2.factory);
  }

private:
  Thing(Factory* factory_) : factory(factory_) {}
  Factory* factory;
};

int main() {
  Thing::Factory f1;
  Thing t11 = f1.make();
  Thing t12 = f1.make();
  Thing::combine(t11, t12);

  Thing::Factory f2;
  Thing t21 = f2.make();
  Thing t22 = f2.make();
  Thing::combine(t21, t22);

  Thing::combine(t11, t21); // Assertion failure
}
```

**Question**: is there a way to do that *during compilation*?

I've tried making `Thing` a template:

```
template<typename Tag>
struct Thing {
  // Same code as before
};
```

And modifying client code to:

```
struct Tag1;
struct Tag2;

int main() {
  Thing<Tag1>::Factory f1;
  Thing<Tag1> t11 = f1.make();
  Thing<Tag1> t12 = f1.make();
  Thing<Tag1>::combine(t11, t12);

  Thing<Tag2>::Factory f2;
  Thing<Tag2> t21 = f2.make();
  Thing<Tag2> t22 = f2.make();
  Thing<Tag2>::combine(t21, t22);
}
```

Then there is no way to `combine` `t11` and `t21`. OK.

But there are still issues:

- nothing forbids to create another `Thing<Tag1>::Factory` and to `combine` the `Thing`s it `make`s with `t11`
- client has to manually declare tag types

Is there a pattern that could solve those as well?

Comment: make a factory factory that handles creating new factories?

Comment: Make `f1` and `f2` different types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before answering, it sounds like you're having an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem); and - I doubt you've chosen the right Y. Consider dropping these factories altogether, or alternatively - using just one factory for many classes with a common base class.

---

For this to be possible at compile-time, either the factories need to produce values of different types, or `combine()` has to be able to run at compile time. But making `combine()` constexpr wouldn't help you, since the factories only produce output at run time... so yes, type differentiation is your only option. Some sort of tagging is fine, I suppose - but if you can provide these tags apriori, why not just have different types from the get-go? Like you said yourself, it's not clear where these tags are supposed to come from.

Anyway, to forbid creating two factories of the same type, you can use a [singleton pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern). The factory works at runtime anyway, might as well let it be created at runtime.

Comment: I indeed had an X-Y problem and ended-up choosing a totally different design. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: I accepted this answer because its second paragraph states conditions required to be able to check during compilation.

Answer (score 0):

> - nothing forbids to create another Thing::Factory and to combine the Things it makes with t11

You can have a common factory base, which keeps a static `std::set` of tag `std::type_info` instances initialized in the factory constructors.

If the entry is already in that `std::set`, you can throw a runtime exception

> - client has to manually declare tag types

You can also generate IDs for the factory instances instead of having a template parameter.